# how to redirect jsp application to php application vtiger without login page like sso

Tags: php, .htaccess, jsp, csrf, vtigercrm

Actually I am trying to login the `vtiger`application without login page. so i am redirecting my `jsp` application to following `php` application url. it throws the following `error`.

> {"success":false,"error":{"code":"Illegal request","message":"Illegal request"}}

**NOTE:**
if i use the `php` url link directly into browser it login successfully.

i think may be htaccess problem or site url problem or csrf token problem. what should i do here

This is my `jsp` url

```
http://192.168.1.x:8080/Admin/index.jsp
```

This is my php url

```
http://192.168.1.x/vtiger/index.php?module=Users&action=Login&return_module=Users&return_action=Login&username=admin&password=xxxxx
```

Thanks advance...

Comment: Does that `vtiger` thing (whatever that is) _really_ expect the credentials as GET parameters? That would be a _huge_ security issue...

Comment: i want login by the parameters @arkascha

Comment: ya i knwo get parameter not secure . but i want know the reason why not login . if i put the url directly inot browser it login successfully . @arkascha

Comment: please help me ou t

Comment: please help me out guys

Comment: If the same URL works when trying manually with a browser, then there must be some other difference between the succeeding and the failing request. Could be something like a HTTP referred or a cookie, we cannot say. You will have to use a network sniffer to capture both requests and compare them in detail. That should point our some specific differences which you can then try to mimic with your cURL request.

Comment: i am not using cURL i just redirect jsp appliction to php link(i.e above specified link ). @arkascha

Comment: OK, sorry, but does that make a difference? Obviously the two requests are different. You have to find out in what critical details they differ and mimic that.

Comment: how can find that any idea ? @arkascha

Comment: I explained that two comments ago, actually.

Comment: okay i will try and let you know that .